# Incrementing register pair

Tags: c

I'm doing an assignment in C that emulates an Intel 8080 microprocessor. One of the instructions is to increment and decrement a register pair (INX and DCX), to do this we were told to use this code :

```
temp = (long)Registers[REGISTER_X] << 8 + (long)Registers[REGISTER_X];
```

where `X` is the letter for the register (A,B,C,D etc.)

It's my understanding that this will first add the two registers together and then shift something (I'm not sure what?) to the left by 8 bits.

This is similar for decrementing for that we use:

```
temp = (long)Registers[REGISTER_X] << 8 - (long)Registers[REGISTER_X];
```

Could anyone explain how this increments the register pair and what is being shifted in this operation as I'm a little confused.

Thanks for the reply I didn't think it did I don't know where they got that code from.
Would something like this be more appropriate?

```
temp = ((WORD)Registers[REGISTER_B] << 8) + (WORD)Registers[REGISTER_C];
temp++;
Registers[REGISTER_B] = (BYTE) (temp >> 8) & 0xFF;
Registers[REGISTER_C] = (BYTE) (temp & 0xFF);
```

Comment: That doesn't look right to me. First of all, to be clear, you really mean `temp = (long)Registers[REGISTER_X] << 8 + (long)Registers[REGISTER_YX];` where `X` and `Y` are either `B` and `C`, `D` and `E`, or `H` and `L` which are the valid pairs to use on the 8080. Secondly, `temp` in this assignment will have the 16-bit value of the register pair. The expression does not increment the register. You would increment it by incrementing the `temp` value, then assigning it back to the `Registers` array. So the second `temp` assignment with the minus doesn't make sense.

Comment: Another problem is that [addition and subtraction operators have higher precedence than bit shifting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence), so you will be shifting the bits a lot more than necessary

Answer (score 1):

If your Register vector uses BYTE elements, you could use this one liner:

```
Registers[REGISTER_B] += ((++Registers[REGISTER_C]) == 0)? 1 : 0;
```